# How to find the latitude and longitude at X distance from a point?

Tags: c#, php, mysql, windows-phone-8, geolocation

I am developing a location tracking app and I am trying to figure out all my friend's position within 1000 mtr radius of my current location. What is the best way to do this?

One way I can think is to calculate distance between my location and with all my friend's locations and see if it is less than 1000 mtr. But this will require more time to go through each entry in DB and calculate for each, most of which might be in from very far place.

I was thinking of something else too. I want the locations within a circular area. If I can get the coordinates of the square that encloses the circle, I can filter my result set to only coordinates within that square (between a particular set of latitute and longitude in degree) and then I can calculate the distance to each entry. How do I do this? **How do I get this max latitude and longitude?** Also will my SQL query be just like *min < (each.location.degree) < max*

Let me know if there is any better alternative. I am not worried about extreme accuracy but performance. I am using WP8 so the coordinates are in format **Lat : 47.626, Long: -121.989**.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is better to start with a rectangle.
the min/max latitude and longitude around the coordinates mylat,mylon with distance dist (in km) can be calculated as follows:

```
set lon1 = mylon-dist/abs(cos(radians(mylat)) * 111);
set lon2 = mylon+dist/abs(cos(radians(mylat)) * 111);
set lat1 = mylat-(dist/111); 
set lat2 = mylat+(dist/111);
```

The exact distance for all points within that rectangle can be calculated by:

```
6367 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((origin.latitude -destination.latitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) +   COS(origin.latitude * pi()/180) * COS(destination.latitude * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((origin.longitude -destination.longitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) as distance
```

Comment: Can you share some resources where I can understand the logic behind this formula ?

Comment: http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/ explains fairly straightforward the mysql logic. For the formula, go to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

Comment: Just for heads up, for several languages, if dist is less than 111 and is int, you will have to divide dist by 111.0 instead or make your dist as float to make sure the output is in float, otherwise, dist/111 may come out as 0(int).

Answer (score 0):

Actually your post raises several questions.

1. How to calculate the distance between two GPS-Positions.
2. How to retrieve a selection of data efficiently from a database when the selection is based on 2-dimensional data (e.g. a position).

A good solution probably solves both problems at the same time: a **spatial database**. If you have a database that supports 2-dim positions (often referred to as geo data) then that database will allow you to query for the distance between two positions and will provide a selection based on that. I have worked with ORACLE spatial data, but there should be support for spatial data in most database systems nowadays.

A few hints on alternative (less precise) approaches:
A GPS position in the LAT/LON format is difficult to handle. If you dont want to determine the distance to other positions on the other end of the world, but in a small radius, you could transform the position into a simple 2d format (cue [map projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection)).
Then your database could store those X/Y coordinates and do simple queries like "get all positions in the square around position x/y" like you hinted.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As you already guess, you'll get more performance to calculate the rectangle around your location and to detect all objects being inside it than a more complex radius-search.

Have a look at the paragraph "Destination point given distance and bearing from start point" on this page: 
http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html